# Xcode error: Missing 'beta-reports-active' entitlement

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Error in provisioning profile: Missing beta-reports-active entitlement.

I've been trying to fix this error for days, but no luck so far.

I have start getting this error post Xcode 9.3 upgrade, since then I'm not able to generate ipa for development environment, however the production looks good.

I have tried generating provisioning profile multiple time, have reinstalled xcode, have removed the app directory and again setup everything but no success.

All the post related to this issue on stackoverflow looks very old.

Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUtrs.png)

Answer (score 3):

This looks much like a bug on Xcode 9.3 as it should not require this for the development or ad hoc build but other people are seeing this as well.

Refer to https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/304085

Comment: Thanks! I have raised a bug report for this issue.

Comment: Please note that this issue randomly pops in Xcode 9.2 as well. And I've tested the recent 9.4 beta, and it has the same problem.

Comment: I tested 9.4 beta 2 today. It is working for me now. And apple stated it's fixed in the release notes of beta 2.